# Second monitor via VGA detected but not working (radeon)

Tags: multiple-monitors, 16.04, radeon, amd-graphics

After the update to Ubuntu 16.04, my second monitor connected via VGA to my Asus laptop stopped working. I am aware of the removal of the `fglrx` driver, but I only became aware of it after the upgrade.

The monitor is detected correctly via the "Displays" app, but it shows no output. I tried another monitor, but that one also did not work.

Laptop is an Asus R510ZE-DM105H.

Graphics card is identified as `Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kaveri [Radeon R7 Graphics] [1002:130c] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])`.

Can I use another driver for this graphic card that supports multiple monitors? There seem to be two drivers around, `radeon` and `amdgpu`?
Or should I report a bug?

If any other information is needed, I will be happy to provide it.

Debug info:

```
ruben@rubuntu:~$ lspci -vvnn | grep VGA
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kaveri [Radeon R7 Graphics] [1002:130c] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV+ VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV+ VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle+ MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+

ruben@rubuntu:~$ dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-22-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=7e6abfec-afe6-4f7e-922f-f042b54d696c ro quiet splash radeon.dpm=1 radeon.modeset=1 vt.handoff=7
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-22-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=7e6abfec-afe6-4f7e-922f-f042b54d696c ro quiet splash radeon.dpm=1 radeon.modeset=1 vt.handoff=7
[    1.195119] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    1.234445] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[    1.241516] fb: switching to radeondrmfb from EFI VGA
[    1.242051] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (KAVERI 0x1002:0x130C 0x1043:0x222D).
[    1.242067] [drm] register mmio base: 0xFEB00000
[    1.242068] [drm] register mmio size: 262144
[    1.242074] [drm] doorbell mmio base: 0xD0000000
[    1.242076] [drm] doorbell mmio size: 8388608
[    1.242082] [drm] ACPI VFCT contains a BIOS for 00:01.0 1002:130c, size 62976
[    1.242181] radeon 0000:00:01.0: VRAM: 1024M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000003FFFFFFF (1024M used)
[    1.242184] radeon 0000:00:01.0: GTT: 2048M 0x0000000040000000 - 0x00000000BFFFFFFF
[    1.242186] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=1024M, BAR=256M
[    1.242187] [drm] RAM width 128bits DDR
[    1.242276] [drm] radeon: 1024M of VRAM memory ready
[    1.242277] [drm] radeon: 2048M of GTT memory ready.
[    1.242290] [drm] Loading kaveri Microcode
[    1.242423] [drm] Internal thermal controller without fan control
[    1.244006] [drm] radeon: dpm initialized
[    1.246500] [drm] Found VCE firmware/feedback version 40.2.2 / 15!
[    1.246512] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 524288, num gpu pages 524288
[    1.262949] [drm] PCIE GART of 2048M enabled (table at 0x0000000000324000).
[    1.263108] radeon 0000:00:01.0: WB enabled
[    1.263128] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8801c2126c00
[    1.263132] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff8801c2126c04
[    1.263134] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff8801c2126c08
[    1.263137] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8801c2126c0c
[    1.263139] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff8801c2126c10
[    1.263698] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000076c98 and cpu addr 0xffffc90002036c98
[    1.264317] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 6 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c18 and cpu addr 0xffff8801c2126c18
[    1.264323] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fence driver on ring 7 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c1c and cpu addr 0xffff8801c2126c1c
[    1.264327] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    1.264329] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    1.264365] radeon 0000:00:01.0: radeon: using MSI.
[    1.264427] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[    1.267460] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 3 usecs
[    1.267545] [drm] ring test on 1 succeeded in 2 usecs
[    1.267558] [drm] ring test on 2 succeeded in 2 usecs
[    1.267730] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 4 usecs
[    1.267736] [drm] ring test on 4 succeeded in 3 usecs
[    1.313425] [drm] ring test on 5 succeeded in 1 usecs
[    1.333285] [drm] UVD initialized successfully.
[    1.442504] [drm] ring test on 6 succeeded in 17 usecs
[    1.442515] [drm] ring test on 7 succeeded in 3 usecs
[    1.442516] [drm] VCE initialized successfully.
[    1.445213] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    1.943854] [drm] ib test on ring 1 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    2.443762] [drm] ib test on ring 2 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    2.443834] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    2.443889] [drm] ib test on ring 4 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    2.963764] [drm] ib test on ring 5 succeeded
[    2.984471] [drm] ib test on ring 6 succeeded
[    2.985225] [drm] ib test on ring 7 succeeded
[    2.988044] [drm] radeon atom DIG backlight initialized
[    2.988049] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[    2.988050] [drm] Connector 0:
[    2.988052] [drm]   VGA-1
[    2.988054] [drm]   HPD2
[    2.988056] [drm]   DDC: 0x6540 0x6540 0x6544 0x6544 0x6548 0x6548 0x654c 0x654c
[    2.988057] [drm]   Encoders:
[    2.988059] [drm]     CRT1: INTERNAL_UNIPHY2
[    2.988060] [drm]     CRT1: NUTMEG
[    2.988062] [drm] Connector 1:
[    2.988063] [drm]   HDMI-A-1
[    2.988064] [drm]   HPD3
[    2.988066] [drm]   DDC: 0x6550 0x6550 0x6554 0x6554 0x6558 0x6558 0x655c 0x655c
[    2.988067] [drm]   Encoders:
[    2.988068] [drm]     DFP1: INTERNAL_UNIPHY2
[    2.988069] [drm] Connector 2:
[    2.988070] [drm]   eDP-1
[    2.988071] [drm]   HPD1
[    2.988073] [drm]   DDC: 0x6530 0x6530 0x6534 0x6534 0x6538 0x6538 0x653c 0x653c
[    2.988074] [drm]   Encoders:
[    2.988076] [drm]     LCD1: INTERNAL_UNIPHY
[    3.502397] [drm] fb mappable at 0xB0728000
[    3.502402] [drm] vram apper at 0xB0000000
[    3.502404] [drm] size 8294400
[    3.502406] [drm] fb depth is 24
[    3.502407] [drm]    pitch is 7680
[    3.502640] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    3.502791] radeon 0000:00:01.0: fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[    3.533832] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.43.0 20080528 for 0000:00:01.0 on minor 0
[    3.533954] radeon 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    3.534299] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (HAINAN 0x1002:0x6665 0x1043:0x130C).
[    3.534314] [drm] register mmio base: 0xFEA00000
[    3.534316] [drm] register mmio size: 262144
[    3.572197] [drm] GPU not posted. posting now...
[    3.575972] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 2048M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000007FFFFFFF (2048M used)
[    3.575976] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 2048M 0x0000000080000000 - 0x00000000FFFFFFFF
[    3.575978] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=2048M, BAR=256M
[    3.575980] [drm] RAM width 64bits DDR
[    3.575996] [drm] radeon: 2048M of VRAM memory ready
[    3.575997] [drm] radeon: 2048M of GTT memory ready.
[    3.576013] [drm] Loading hainan Microcode
[    3.576194] [drm] Internal thermal controller without fan control
[    3.576290] [drm] probing gen 2 caps for device 1022:1425 = 733d01/e
[    3.585048] [drm] radeon: dpm initialized
[    3.585054] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 524288, num gpu pages 524288
[    3.587725] [drm] probing gen 2 caps for device 1022:1425 = 733d01/e
[    3.587732] [drm] enabling PCIE gen 3 link speeds, disable with radeon.pcie_gen2=0
[    4.933946] [drm] PCIE GART of 2048M enabled (table at 0x0000000000040000).
[    4.934087] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[    4.934091] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8801c1db1c00
[    4.934094] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff8801c1db1c04
[    4.934096] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff8801c1db1c08
[    4.934098] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8801c1db1c0c
[    4.934100] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff8801c1db1c10
[    4.934103] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VCE init error (-22).
[    4.934106] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    4.934107] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    4.934109] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit
[    4.934146] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: using MSI.
[    4.934175] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[    5.142046] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
[    5.142057] [drm] ring test on 1 succeeded in 1 usecs
[    5.142063] [drm] ring test on 2 succeeded in 1 usecs
[    5.142073] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 4 usecs
[    5.142082] [drm] ring test on 4 succeeded in 4 usecs
[    5.142539] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    5.142624] [drm] ib test on ring 1 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    5.142653] [drm] ib test on ring 2 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    5.142675] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    5.142696] [drm] ib test on ring 4 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    5.143684] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[    5.145683] [drm:radeon_acpi_init [radeon]] *ERROR* Cannot find a backlight controller
[    5.145768] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.43.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[   20.391589] [drm] probing gen 2 caps for device 1022:1425 = 733d01/e
[   20.391595] [drm] enabling PCIE gen 3 link speeds, disable with radeon.pcie_gen2=0
[   21.737529] [drm] PCIE GART of 2048M enabled (table at 0x0000000000040000).
[   21.737673] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[   21.737677] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8801c1db1c00
[   21.737680] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff8801c1db1c04
[   21.737682] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff8801c1db1c08
[   21.737685] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8801c1db1c0c
[   21.737687] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff8801c1db1c10
[   21.737689] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VCE init error (-22).
[   22.352776] [drm:r600_ring_test [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: ring 0 test failed (scratch(0x850C)=0xCAFEDEAD)
[   22.352806] [drm:si_resume [radeon]] *ERROR* si startup failed on resume
[   48.571322] [drm:atom_op_jump [radeon]] *ERROR* atombios stuck in loop for more than 5secs aborting
[   48.571348] [drm:atom_execute_table_locked [radeon]] *ERROR* atombios stuck executing 6D24 (len 254, WS 0, PS 4) @ 0x6D32
[   48.571366] [drm:atom_execute_table_locked [radeon]] *ERROR* atombios stuck executing 6690 (len 78, WS 12, PS 8) @ 0x66C9
[   48.579002] [drm] probing gen 2 caps for device 1022:1425 = 733d01/e
[   48.579009] [drm] enabling PCIE gen 3 link speeds, disable with radeon.pcie_gen2=0
[   50.317520] radeon 0000:01:00.0: Wait for MC idle timedout !
[   50.516591] radeon 0000:01:00.0: Wait for MC idle timedout !
[   50.522599] [drm] PCIE GART of 2048M enabled (table at 0x0000000000040000).
[   50.522710] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[   50.522714] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8801c1db1c00
[   50.522716] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff8801c1db1c04
[   50.522718] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff8801c1db1c08
[   50.522721] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8801c1db1c0c
[   50.522723] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff8801c1db1c10
[   50.522725] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VCE init error (-22).
[   51.133864] [drm:r600_ring_test [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: ring 0 test failed (scratch(0x850C)=0xCAFEDEAD)
[   51.133890] [drm:si_resume [radeon]] *ERROR* si startup failed on resume
[  139.992369] [drm:radeon_dp_link_train [radeon]] *ERROR* clock recovery reached max voltage
[  139.992421] [drm:radeon_dp_link_train [radeon]] *ERROR* clock recovery failed
[  140.102775] [drm:radeon_dp_link_train [radeon]] *ERROR* clock recovery reached max voltage
[  140.102816] [drm:radeon_dp_link_train [radeon]] *ERROR* clock recovery failed
[  164.383949] [drm:radeon_dp_link_train [radeon]] *ERROR* clock recovery reached max voltage
[  164.383991] [drm:radeon_dp_link_train [radeon]] *ERROR* clock recovery failed
[  164.494621] [drm:radeon_dp_link_train [radeon]] *ERROR* clock recovery reached max voltage
[  164.494656] [drm:radeon_dp_link_train [radeon]] *ERROR* clock recovery failed
```

Comment: I have the same issue with a Kaveri-based desktop mainboard. BIOS displays fine on the second (VGA) monitor but Ubuntu doesn't.